# How to set a ClientID in Perl module Net::MQTT::Simple (MQTT interface)?

Tags: perl, mqtt

I would like to use the Perl module `Net::MQTT::Simple` to send MQTT messages to a MQTT server. This is a simple MVP script based on the [CPAN documentation of Net::MQTT::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::MQTT::Simple):

```
#!/usr/bin perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use Net::MQTT::Simple;
 
# Allow unencrypted connection with credentials
$ENV{MQTT_SIMPLE_ALLOW_INSECURE_LOGIN} = 1;
 
# Connect to broker
my $mqtt = Net::MQTT::Simple->new('localhost:1883');
 
my $mqtt_username = 'username';
my $mqtt_password = 'verysecretpassword';

# Depending if authentication is required, login to the broker
if($mqtt_username and $mqtt_password) {
    $mqtt->login($mqtt_username, $mqtt_password);
}

# Publish a message
$mqtt->publish("home/temperature", "20.5");
$mqtt->disconnect();
```

My problem is: I need to specify a client id in the transmission so that the message is correctly processed by the receiving MQTT server. Any help is appreciated!
Daniel

edit: OK it's answered. Not possible. I guess I'll have to stick with my current solution execute `mosquitto_pub` from within the Per script, which let's me specify a client ID.

Comment: It might be possible to derive a subclass from `Net::MQTT::Simple` and override method `_client_identifier()` to return the ID as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing an override for `_client_identifier()` might solve your problem:

```
#!/usr/bin perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use Net::MQTT::Simple;

package Net::MQTT::Simple::ID;

our @ISA = 'Net::MQTT::Simple';

sub _client_identifier{
    return 'My_custom_client_id';
}

package main;
# Allow unencrypted connection with credentials
$ENV{MQTT_SIMPLE_ALLOW_INSECURE_LOGIN} = 1;
 
# Connect to broker
my $mqtt = Net::MQTT::Simple::ID->new('localhost:1883');
 
my $mqtt_username = 'username';
my $mqtt_password = 'verysecretpassword';

# Depending if authentication is required, login to the broker
if($mqtt_username and $mqtt_password) {
    $mqtt->login($mqtt_username, $mqtt_password);
}

# Publish a message
$mqtt->publish("home/temperature", "20.5");
$mqtt->disconnect();

__END__

nc -lv 127.0.0.1 1883 | od -c
Listening on localhost 1883
Connection received on localhost 55172
0000000 020   =  \0 004   M   Q   T   T 004 302  \0   <  \0 023   M   y
0000020   _   c   u   s   t   o   m   _   c   l   i   e   n   t   _   i
0000040   d  \0  \b   u   s   e   r   n   a   m   e  \0 022   v   e   r
0000060   y   s   e   c   r   e   t   p   a   s   s   w   o   r   d   0
0000100 026  \0 020   h   o   m   e   /   t   e   m   p   e   r   a   t
0000120   u   r   e   2   0   .   5 340  \0
0000131
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Many many thanks, what a cool solution! - Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source [code](https://github.com/Juerd/Net-MQTT-Simple/blob/master/lib/Net/MQTT/Simple.pm#L30) you don't.

The code generates a random client id and there is no way to update it.

I suggest you look at an alternative, e.g. the Python Paho library.

Answer (score 0):

You need override _client_identifier method of Net::MQTT::Simple.

You can do it in one line:

```
*{Net::MQTT::Simple::_client_identifier} = sub { return 'my_client_id'; };
```